# Is there an integrable function mapping a closed interval to an open interval

Tags: integration

Is there a function $f$ that is integrable on a closed interval $[a,b]$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and maps this interval to an open but bounded interval?

**Edit:**

I should have specified better. What I wanted was more of a function $f$ with a primitive function $F$ (that is $F' = f$ on $(a, b)$ and the one-sided limits of $F'$ are $f(a)$ resp $f(b)$).

Answer (score 4):

Sure.  $f(0)=f(2)=1$, and $f(x)=x$ for $0 \lt x \lt 2$.

Comment: Thank you. This indeed answers my question (as stated) but not as meant.

Answer (score 2):

What about $f:[0,2]\to(0,1)$ defined as $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=1/2$, $f(x)=x$ in $(0,1)$ and $f(x)=2-x$ on $(1,2)$?

Comment: Thank you. This indeed answers my question. But I should have specified better.